# Tkinter Create buttons from list with different image

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create button from a list and I want them to have their own image.
I have tried this but only the last created button work.

```
liste_boutton = ['3DS','DS','GB']

for num,button_name in enumerate(liste_boutton):
    button = Button(type_frame)
    button['bg'] = "grey72"
    photo = PhotoImage(file=".\dbinb\img\\{}.png".format(button_name))
    button.config(image=photo, width="180", height="50")
    button.grid(row=num, column=0, pady=5, padx=8)
```

Comment: See *every question about putting an image on a Button, ever* - you have to keep a reference to the image somewhere or it will be garbage collected.  `button.img = photo` perhaps.

Comment: what does "only the last created button work" mean? Did all the buttons appear but only the last one had an image? Did only lthe last button appear?

Comment: do you get error message when you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe ?

Comment: @BryanOakley The last button created work (can click) and have an image. All otther button have no image and can't click.

Comment: @jasonharper and my question is how you do that with a list.

Comment: @furas I get an error when I click on whatever button (with image or not): 
  File "H:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "H:\collector\function.py", line 43, in type_boutton_color
    button.config(bg="grey72")
  File "H:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1479, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "H:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1470, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist

Comment: always add error message in question - it is aways useful information. and it will be more readable.

Comment: I see `image "pyimage2" doesn't exist `  in error so problem can be `garbage collected` - see first comment.

Comment: read **Note:** at the bottom of the page [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: @furas I can't figured out how to do this with list

Comment: did you try to use `button.img = photo` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only your last button has an image as it is the only one that has reference in the global scope, or in any scope for that matter in your specific case. As is, you have only one referable button and image objects, namely `button` and `photo`.

Short answer would be:

```
photo = list()
for...
    photo.append(PhotoImage(file=".\dbinb\img\\{}.png".format(button_name)))
```

But this would still have bad practice written all over it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears okay, but you are need to keep a reference of the image [effbot](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm) and also I do believe PhotoImage can only read [GIF and PGM/PPM images from files](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm), so you need another library PIL seems to be a good choice. I used a couple images from a google search for the images, they were placed in the same directory as my .py file, so i changed the code a little bit. Also the button width and height can cut off parts of the image if not careful.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
type_frame = Tk()

liste_boutton = ['3DS','DS','GB']

for num,button_name in enumerate(liste_boutton):
    button = Button(type_frame)
    button['bg'] = "grey72" 
    # this example works, if .py and images in same directory
    image = Image.open("{}.png".format(button_name))
    image = image.resize((180, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS) # resize the image to ratio needed, but there are better ways
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image) # to support png, etc image files
    button.image = photo # save reference
    button.config(image=photo, width="180", height="100")
    # be sure to check the width and height of the images, so there is no cut off
    button.grid(row=num, column=0, pady=5, padx=8)

mainloop()
```

Output:
  [https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxthT.png]

Comment: describe problem and solution

Answer (score 0):

With all your comments I was able to achieve what I expected ! 
Thank ! I'm new to programming so this will not necessarily be the best solution but it works

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
liste_boutton = ['3DS','DS','GB']
button = list()
photo = list()
for num,button_name in enumerate(liste_boutton):
    button.append(tk.Button(frame1))
    photo.append(tk.PhotoImage(file=".\dbinb\img\\{}.png".format(button_name)))
    button[-1].config(bg="grey72",image=photo[-1], width="180", height="50")
    button[-1].grid(row=num,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```